# Appending to a URL with powershell

Tags: powershell

```
function Get-Data(){
    [PSObject[]]$pid = ''

    $getUri1 = 'https://playbook2.com/data/project/folder/28220'
    $projectIds = wget $getUri1 -UseDefaultCredentials |
    ConvertFrom-JSON | Select data | select -Expand data | select id

    Write-Host $projectIds

    #obtain all the project ids
    ForEach-Object{    
        [PSObject[]]$pid += $projectIds.id
    }

    Write-Host $pid

    $uri3 = "https://playbook2.com/data/project/export/projects-tasks?projectIds[]="
    $getIds = [PSObject[]]$pid -join "&projectIds[]=" 
    $getUri2 = $uri3 + $getIds
    $of = "\\ant\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\Time_Tracking_Tasks.xlsx"

    Write-Host $getUri2

    #retrieve excel files of tasks from each sub-folder
    wget $getUri2 -outfile $of -UseDefaultCredentials
}
```

This code is an adaptation of some other code that I wrote.  The 5 other scripts work fine.  The main difference is that the other code has to loop through multiple folders and gets the project IDs under each folder, but this code only has to go through a single folder.  Now in the other code the `$uri3`, `$getIds` code works fine and I get an export.  The problem I am seeing in this code is that it isn't joining the URL the way I expect.

https://playbook2.com/data/project/export/projects-tasks?projectIds[]=######&projectIds[]=####### is the expected and previously seen output to get all the project data i need.

The problem with the above script is that it is giving https://playbook2.com/data/project/export/projects-tasks?projectIds[]=&projectIds[]=######&projectIds[]=####### which is invalid.

is there a way that I can tell it to do just $pid for the first item in the object and then -join the `"&projectIds[]="` on the next n until the end of the list?  I tried

```
[PSObject[]]$pid | select -Skip 1 -join "&projectIds[]="
```

and

```
[PSObject[]]$pid | Select-Object -Skip 1 -join "&projectIds[]="
```

but that results in nothing being appended.

Comment: `([PSObject[]]$pid | Select-Object -Skip 1) -join "&projectIds[]="`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of "mistakes" in your script.

First is that you are using the variable `$pid` which is an system default variable. You can check the system global variables by typing

```
Get-Variable
```

Secondly $pid is defined with an empty string. The correct way to initialize a PSObject is with `$myVar = New-Object PSObject`. Replace `[PSObject[]]$pid = ''` with `$myProjectIds = New-Object PSObject`

For readability I took the liberty to rewrite your script.

```
function Get-Data(){
    $GetProjectsUri = 'https://playbook2.com/data/project/folder/28220'
    $ExportProjectsUri = 'https://playbook2.com/data/project/export/projects-tasks?'
    $ExportFilePath = "\\ant\dept\DCGSI\Extracts\Time_Tracking_Tasks.xlsx"

    $GetProjectsJson = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $GetProjectsUri -UseDefaultCredentials
    Write-Output $GetProjectsJson 

    $Projects = ConvertFrom-JSON -InputObject $GetProjectsJson
    Write-Output $Projects

    foreach ($Project in $Projects) {
        $ProjectId = $Project.data.id

        # Check if ProjectId exists
        if ($ProjectId) {
            $ExportProjectsUri = $ExportProjectsUri + 'projectIds[]=' + $ProjectId
        }
    }

    Write-Output $ExportProjectsUri

    Invoke-WebRequest Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $ExportProjectsUri -outfile $ExportFilePath -UseDefaultCredentials
}
```

Cheers
Glenn

Comment: Glenn, thanks for the info and the clean-up.  I'll look at cleaning up my scripts with your re-write as I can.  I don't do this very much, it is a as necessary thing so it helps me to see cleaner code.